# How to join the same table multiple times

Tags: syntax, table, join

Consider some test table

```
tab=Table[{i,i^2},{i,1,100,1}];
```

I would like to obtain the table

```
tab2=Join[tab,tab,...,tab]
```

where ... include some number of tab, in a compact and smart way. Say, for 10 tab, the stupid way would be

```
tab2=Join[tab,tab,tab,tab,tab,tab,tab,tab,tab,tab]
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

My guess is

```
tab[n_]:=Flatten[Table[tab2,{i,1,n,1}],1]
```

But I have doubts whether it will be fast in case of large tables.

Comment: To do this say 20 times, `tab3 = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[tab, 20]`?

Comment: `tab4 = Catenate[Table[tab, 20]]`

Comment: `tab5 = Fold[Join, ConstantArray[tab, 20]]`

Comment: `tab6 = Sequence @@@ ConstantArray[tab, 20]`

Comment: Looks like a possible x-y problem. What is the actual goal?

Comment: For tab5, I suggest Join instead of fold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tab2 == Join @@ ConstantArray[tab, 10]
(*    True    *)
```